Use slots or yield in Livewire partial components (not full-page/layout components)
I'm attempting to create a custom select drop-down for a project but can't get slots or yielding content to work. Is this possible in livewire components when none of them are full-page components?
For example, if I have a parent component, parent-component.blade.php, can I have a slot within a child component referenced in the parent component that references the content passed into it?
Something like:
parent-component.blade.php
(contains some $dataArray)
<div>
  <livewire:child-component>
    <x-slot>
      @for($dataArray as $item)
        <span>$item</span>
      @endfor
    </x-slot>
  </livewire:child-component>
</div>

then in the child-component.blade.php
<div>
  {{--- something something ---}}
  
  {{ $slot }} // should print everything inside of <x-slot> in parent
  
  {{--- something something ---}}
</div>

I've tried with $slot notation and also @yield and each time I get errors. Is this not possible unless you are using slots within a layout component?
My goal is to create a set of nestable components for a livewire component library. I want sections that can accept anything.
My current issue is that I can't pass an array to a child component, either! So if I can't pass HTML through a slot/yield and I can't pass an array, what other way is there to get data that I need to iterate over into a component?

Slots are not available in Livewire components, if the situation allows it you can use a plain blade component which allows slots
